# Как list хранит информацию?

Tags: c++, std-list

Доброго вечера, у меня возник вопрос, есть программа которая создаёт класс компания, в нём есть лист "Работники", состоящий из классов "Работник", при создание нового элемента и добавление его в лист, он через какое то время может просто пропасть, а может остаться на месте. В чём может быть причина? Лист хранит ссылку на объект и при локальном удаление объекта он пропадает или же лист всё таки копирует информацию объекта в себя и не зависит от локальной жизни объекта?

```
void addStuff(Company& company)
{
  company.hire(Employee("Max Mustermann"));
  company.hire(Employee("Erika Musterfrau"));
}
```

Объект класса Employee создаётся корректно, не буду добавлять его код в листинг

```
class Company
{
  public:
    Company(std::string name);
    virtual ~Company();

    void makeOrder(const char* name, const float price);
    void removeOrdersByProductName(const char* name);

    void hire(Employee employee);
    void fire(const char* name);
    void renameEmployee(const char* old_name, const char* new_name);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Company& company);

  private:
    std::string name_;

    typedef std::list<Employee> EmployeeList;
    EmployeeList employees_;

    typedef std::vector<Order*> OrderVector;
    OrderVector orders_;
};



void Company::hire(Employee employee)
{
    employees_.push_back(employee);
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

```
#include <iostream>
class Company;

class Employee
{
  public:
Employee(const char* name);
Employee(const Employee& copy);
virtual ~Employee();
Employee& operator=(const Employee& copy);

char* getName() { return name_; }

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Employee& employee);
friend Company;

  private:
    char* name_;
    static void copyString(char** dest, const char* source);

};

  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Employee& employee);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем классе лист определен как

```
typedef std::list<Employee> EmployeeList;
```

Следовательно он хранит объекты типа `Employee`. Когда выполняется метод класса `std::list` `push_back`, как в случае данного предложения

```
employees_.push_back(employee);
```

то список создает новый объект, используя конструктор копирования для объекта, переданного методу в качестве аргумента.

Ниже приведена простая демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, что проблем с занесением объектов в класс `std::list` нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

typedef std::string Employee;

class Company
{
public:

    Company( const std::string &name ) : name( name ) {};
    virtual ~Company() = default;

    void hire( const Employee &employee )
    {
        employees.push_back( employee );
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &out, const Company &company );

private:
    std::string name;
    typedef std::list<Employee> EmployeeList;
    EmployeeList employees;
};

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &out, const Company &company )
{
    out << company.name << "(" << company.employees.size() << "): ";

    for ( const auto &employee : company.employees )
    {
        out << "\""a << employee << "\" ";
    }       

    return out << std::endl;
}

void addStuff( Company &company )
{
    company.hire( Employee( "Max Mustermann" ) );
    company.hire( Employee( "Erika Musterfrau" ) );
}

int main() 
{
    Company company( "OwesomeCo" );

    addStuff( company );

    std::cout << company;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
OwesomeCo(2): "Max Mustermann" "Erika Musterfrau"
```

Так что проблема у вас кроется либо в определении класса `Employee`, либо в других функциях, где вы работаете с листом.

Comment: То есть у меня должен быть конструктор копирования, который и скопирует мой созданный объект и вставит его в лист?

Comment: @AntonBarinov Компилятор скорей всего по умолчанию создал за вас конструктор копирования. Если ваш класс содержит какие-то указатели, и требуется делать "глубокую" копию, то тогда вам необходимо создать конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания.

Comment: Employee::Employee(const Employee & copy){
    name_ = copy.name_;
}
 попытался добавить такой конструктор копирования ( никогда с ними раньше не работал ), на сколько он корректен? поведение кода не изменилось

Comment: @AntonBarinov Надо видеть определение этого класса, чтобы с уверенностью сказать, что этого определения достаточно.

Comment: Добавил листинг Employeе в вопрос

Comment: @AntonBarinov Зачем вы храните указатель char * вместо объекта std::string? Я думаю, что проблема с этим связана, так как вы неправильно копируете и присваиваете объекты. Не усложняйте себе жизнь и объявите name_ как std::string name_;

Comment: К сожалению это учебное задание в котором я должен найти все ошибки в коде и исправить их, попробую заменить всё на string

Comment: @AntonBarinov Тогда закрывайте этот вопрос и открывайте новый, в котором спросите, правильно ли определен класс Employee. Вам следует будет показать определения его методов.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользуюсь советом

Comment: А вы знаете, я заменил всё на string и это прекрасно работает, спасибо за помощь !

Comment: @AntonBarinov Как я уже сказал, вам надо было написать конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания, которые правильно копируют строки, адресуемые указателями.